# Printing multiple value with specific width in format

Tags: python

I want to print this with a specific width so that they are aligned when printed.

```
for i in range(len(valuelist)):
    print("{0:<5}  {0:<5}  {0:<5}".format(valuelist[i],averagelist[i],averagesquared[i]))
```

Somehow, it only shows the valuelist[i] to all 3 columns. The averagelist[i], and averagesquared[i] is not getting shown. All 3 of those will only show valuelist[i].

It works properly when I print them like this.

```
for i in range(len(valuelist)):
    print("{}  {}  {}".format(valuelist[i],averagelist[i],averagesquared[i]))
```

It properly works just like how I intended it to be.
I can fix it by putting 2 more prints but I want it to be in a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not using the syntax correctly, it should be:

```
for i in range(len(valuelist)):
    print("{0:<5}  {1:<5}  {2:<5}".format(valuelist[i],averagelist[i],averagesquared[i]))
```

This is the correct way to format it, as the numbers inside the {} refer to the index of the arguments in the format function. If they are all zero instead like in your code, they will all call on the same argument, which is the first one every time.